# Creating selection in stand-alone ArcPy script?

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute, arcgis-10.5, error-000732

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.5.

I have had this work for me before, so I am confused as to what problem I am -running into now. When making a selection to copy to a new dataset in Arcpy, -here is the important part of the code:

```
sortoutput = 'c:/Users/srcha/Desktop/Cluster_Analysis/output/Ld_Playas_extracted1_sorted.shp'
sortedftr = 'C:/Users/srcha/Desktop/Cluster_Analysis/output/Ld_Play_extra_sort_ftr.shp'
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(sortoutput,sortedftr)
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(sortedftr, selection_type="NEW_SELECTION", where_clause='"AREA_ADJ" >=0.07957')
```

This yields the following error:

> ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. Error
>   000732: Layer Name of Table View: data set
>   C:/Users/srcha/Desktop/Cluster_Analysis/output/Ld_Play_extra_sort_ftr.shp
>   does not exist or is not supported
>
> Failed to execute (SelectLayerByAttribute)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cant create a feature layer on disk, it is stored in memory only.

Change:

```
sortedftr = 'C:/Users/srcha/Desktop/Cluster_Analysis/output/Ld_Play_extra_sort_ftr.shp'
```

To:

```
sortedftr = 'sortedftr_lyr'
```

After the selection if you can use Copy features to convert the layer to a shapefile on disk.

You dont actually need Select by attributes, this can be done with the where_clause of Make Feature Layer:

> where_clause (Optional)
>
> An SQL expression used to select a subset of features.